# Answering popular questions should get more points

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I think that those who answer (as in accepted answer) popular questions (as determined by question up-votes) should receive a proportional rep boost.

The basic value should remain the same, but perhaps a scheme such as

0-5  +15 rep
6-10  +20 rep
11-15 +25 rep
16-20 +30 rep
21 - 30 +35 rep
31+  +40 rep

Comment: Why? chr chr chr

Comment: I've noticed on smaller boards (like math.se or ubuntu) there are fairly popular threads (+8 or +10 on the question) where the answerer was given +1 or +2 upvotes, this gives a proportional boost in lieu of answer upvotes for accepted answers.

Comment: -1 This is a bad idea, on so many levels.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are multiple proposals for exactly the opposite

Answer (score 12):

I can see only negative effects from this.

It would discourage people from answering niche, hard questions that have received little attention. Also, what's popular often takes the form of a poll - something that doesn't need to be rewarded by even more reputation.

Comment: Reversal candidate!

Answer (score 7):

Popular questions inherently give more reputation to answerers because more people read them.